# Symfony 3.3 - Twig runtime error with hyphenated form widget name

Tags: symfony, twig, recaptcha

I'm trying to integrate the `BeelabRecaptcha2Bundle` into my project.  As such, I want to name the reCaptcha field itself `g-recaptcha-response`.  When I add it to my Twig template, I get the following error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "Neither the property "g"
>   nor one of the methods "g()", "getg()"/"isg()"/"hasg()" or "__call()"
>   exist and have public access in class
>   "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView"

Here's the offending Twig code:

```
<div>
    {{ form_widget(form.g-recaptcha-response) }}
</div>
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<div>
    {{ form_widget(form['g-recaptcha-response']) }}
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
    {{ form_widget(attribute(form, 'g-recaptcha-response')) }}
</div>
```

You can read more about this in the [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables).